Transactions Order
I am wondering how can I guarantee the order of transactions, For example if we send two transactions as A , B ... they will be coming out as B, A?
I want to prevent that and I want to get A then B.
How can I do that?

If you are the issuer of these two transactions, then the nonce can help you guarantee that. What you want is your transaction A to have the nonce N which should strictly equal your number of transactions and have your transaction B have the nonce N + 1.
Related: Can I use any nonce as long as it is not previously been used?

You can give a higher tip to the miner in the transaction that you want to be first one.
